tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits() output with nan
I am trying to get Mask-RCNN to run with tensorflow. The only variant so far where the training runs without any error messages (e.g. TypeError: unhashable type: 'ListWrapper'), comes from here: https://github.com/maxw1489/Mask_RCNN (with tensorflow 2.9.1). Nevertheless, there are problems that the losses are not calculated correctly. So far I have been able to isolate the error, that the output of mrcnn_class_loss = nan. If you go into the function for calculating this loss (def mrcnn_class_loss_graph(target_class_ids, pred_class_logits, active_class_ids)), then the crucial point is loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target_class_ids, logits=pred_class_logits).
I analyzed the inputs to this function and created the following code snippet that demonstrates this behavior with the nan:
target_class_ids = tf.Variable(np.array([[2, 1, 1, 0]]), dtype=np.int32)
pred_class_logits = tf.Variable(np.array([[[-0.0738682151], [-0.405795932], [-1.68359947], [-2.13260722]]], dtype=np.float32))

print(target_class_ids)
print(pred_class_logits)

loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
      labels=target_class_ids, logits=pred_class_logits)

print(loss)

The output is:
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1, 4) dtype=int32, numpy=array([[2, 1, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)>
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1, 4, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[-0.07386822],
        [-0.40579593],
        [-1.6835995 ],
        [-2.1326072 ]]], dtype=float32)>
tf.Tensor([[nan nan nan  0.]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)

Are the nan's explainable and what can be done to fix the code to resolve the issue? Thank you for your time!!

A version of the matterport mask rcnn that works with tensorflow2? Interesting. You also might consider that keras-cv also has an implementation of maskrcnn.

After testing your code on CPU and GPU, I found some interesting bit. On CPU, I get the following error:

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node _wrapped__SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits_device/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Received a label value of 2 which is outside the valid range of [0, 1).  Label values: 2 1 1 0 [Op:SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits] name:

Interestingly, this error does not come with GPU. There, the nan values appear instead.
It seems that on CPU it is explicitly checked if the logits vector for one prediction is long enough to make all labels possibile. Let me show you an  example with modified code:
target_class_ids = tf.Variable(np.array([[2, 3, 1, 0]]), dtype=np.int32)
pred_class_logits = tf.Variable(np.array([[
    [-0.0738682151,  -0.0052,  0.78],
     [-0.0405795932, -0.0215,  0.32],
     [-1.68359947,   -0.54,   -5.6],
     [-2.13260722,   -0.111,   0.45]]], dtype=np.float32))
loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
      labels=target_class_ids, logits=pred_class_logits)
print(loss)
tf.Tensor([[0.63222516        nan 0.2814241  3.081086  ]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)

CPU output (important part):

Received a label value of 3 which is outside the valid range of [0, 3).  Label values: 2 3 1 0 [Op:SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits] name:

Here, I modified the labels a bit and made the logits vector longer of each prediction.
Notice the nan value at the index of the 3 label? Because with 3 logits per prediction, only 3 labels (0, 1, 2) are possible as output. On CPU, this is explicitly told. "3" as a label is just not possible with only a logits vector of length 3.
In your example, the logits vector for each prediction was only of length 1. So every label that is bigger than "0" goes to nan on GPU, and throws the error on (my) CPU.

I checked the linked repo, and it had a config with NUM_CLASSES=1 as default. Did you override it to the correct number of classes in your case?

Thank you very much for your super-fast reply. In the meantime, I have also found out that CPU and GPU have different behavior in the output by googling on the Internet. I actually use a GPU for the training. In my config class, the number of classes is actually set to 7 (NUM_OF_CLASSES = 7). What I read from your answer is that the individual arrays of pred_class_logits (in my case) must be 8 cells in size so that no more nan's are generated. I.e. I have to go back into the code to see why the original pred_class_logits are created “wrong” ... Thanks again for your advice @mhenning!
